Error during compilation (Java0000) Android .Net MAUI
When I'm trying to compile my .Net MAUI on Android. I get the following java error that I have duplicate

android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver$Stub$Proxy

Gravedad    Código  Descripción Proyecto    Archivo Línea   Estado suprimido    Detalles
Error   JAVA0000    Error in obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\128\jl\classes.jar:android/support/v4/os/IResultReceiver$Stub$Proxy.class:
Type android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver$Stub$Proxy is defined multiple times: obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\128\jl\classes.jar:android/support/v4/os/IResultReceiver$Stub$Proxy.class, obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\33\jl\bin\classes.jar:android/support/v4/os/IResultReceiver$Stub$Proxy.class
Compilation failed
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete, origin: obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\128\jl\classes.jar
android/support/v4/os/IResultReceiver$Stub$Proxy.class
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.R0.a(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:126)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.main(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:5)
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete, origin: obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\128\jl\classes.jar:android/support/v4/os/IResultReceiver$Stub$Proxy.class
    at Version.fakeStackEntry(Version_8.1.56.java:0)
    at com.android.tools.r8.M.a(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:5)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.R0.a(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:81)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.R0.a(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:32)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.R0.a(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:31)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.R0.b(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:2)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.a(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:26)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.b(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:13)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.a(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:24)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.R0.a(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:113)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.b: Type android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver$Stub$Proxy is defined multiple times: obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\128\jl\classes.jar:android/support/v4/os/IResultReceiver$Stub$Proxy.class, obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\33\jl\bin\classes.jar:android/support/v4/os/IResultReceiver$Stub$Proxy.class
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.O2.a(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:21)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.O2.a(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:26)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.A2.a(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:44)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.A2.a(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:10)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.merge(ConcurrentHashMap.java:2056)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.A2.a(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:6)
    at com.android.tools.r8.graph.b4$a.e(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:7)
    at com.android.tools.r8.dex.c.a(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:58)
    at com.android.tools.r8.dex.c.a(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:9)
    at com.android.tools.r8.dex.c.a(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:8)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.a(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:29)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.d(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:17)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.c(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:1)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.R0.a(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:28)
    ... 6 more
Directory 'obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\128' is from 'androidx.core.core.aar'.

I've tried several times to delete the obj and bin folders, to recompile but nothing.
I've thought it might be something from the packages:
<PackageReference Include="CommunityToolkit.Mvvm" Version="8.2.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls" Version="$(MauiVersion)" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility" Version="$(MauiVersion)" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="8.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="sqlite-net-pcl" Version="1.9.172" />
<PackageReference Include="SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_green" Version="2.1.8" />
<PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Duplex" Version="6.0.*" />
<PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Federation" Version="6.0.*" />
<PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Http" Version="6.0.*" />
<PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.NetNamedPipe" Version="6.0.*" />
<PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.NetTcp" Version="6.0.*" />
<PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Security" Version="6.0.*" />
<PackageReference Include="Telerik.UI.for.Maui" Version="6.7.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Xam.Plugin.Geolocator" Version="4.5.0.6" />
<PackageReference Include="Xam.Plugin.Media" Version="6.0.2" />
<PackageReference Include="ZXing.Net.Maui" Version="0.4.0" />
<PackageReference Include="ZXing.Net.Maui.Controls" Version="0.4.0" />

But I don't see any conflict.

New project -> Manage Packages -> Add next package from the list -> Build. If you manage to add all, you will know its not the packages.

I had this problem, very similar to this. When binding MAUI application, running on android, to a service using AIDL. So this android class gets added, build options is set to android interface, and Xamarin writes the Stub for me. But the name of the file has Stub already, and the way this auto-generator code works ... well, long story short, it duplicates a file/class name. So I went down the road to remove everything I have added, clean, and re-add it again to the project. It is not your case exactly, just sharing so you get basic idea how such things happen.

@H.A.H. if I do a New project with the same packages and I compile, I have the same error

I've seen that the Xam.Plugin package is for Xamarin.Essential, so it may be that since maui already has an API for the camera @H.A.H.

Well if you already know where the problem is, this is half of the solution. Now find a way to run the package in MAUI, or search for replacements.

I'm going to try to fix it, I'm going to remove the two xam.plugin package and look for something for MAUI that apparently has both. Thanks for the info @H.A.H.

The problem has been that several NuGet packages conflicted, so I deleted the xamarin ones that were bothering me and used the maui tools.
